# List of Active Objects

Tags: java

I am trying to do something like below.

Class A - It is a Class having static member variables and also it extends from the thread Class. It has a static arraylist of Class B objects.

Class B - Just a Class whose objects need to register to class A, on registration the thread from Class A would call certain methods of the objects continuously at some interval.

```
class A extends Thread
{
    private static A a;
    private static ArrayList objsClassB;
    void run()
    {
      /* infinitely iterate through the objsClassB objects and call certain methods..
         in try and catch */
    }

    public static void StartEmulating() {
        if(a == null)
        {
            a = new A();
            a.start();
        }
    }   
    public static void registerToA(B m1)
    {
       objsClassB.add(m1);
    }

}

class B
{
   B()
   {
     registerToA(this);
   }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   A.StartEmulating();
   B b1 = new B();
   B b2 = new B();
   //make b2 = null to simulate object deletion...
   b2 = null;
}
```

Now, what i want to do is that if due to some reason b2 got deleted(i.e. lets say the thread in which it was created got crashed) i want to deregister that from the list but that is not happening.
Is there a way for me to store the b2 in the list ?

Comment: `private A a;` should probably be `private static A a;`

Comment: an approach maybe to store only `WeakReference`s  in `A`

Comment: yup sorry, private A a; was private static A a; only...by mistake had done edited the post.

Comment: @Lino thanks WeakReference is what i needed, but it only works if i make b2 = null and call garbage collector explicitly in the main method. after main's execution even if i am waiting for more time then also it is still shown as active object.

Comment: you can not control or predict if or when the GC will do its job in a reliable way. and you can not guarantee that an object only held by weak references will be reclaimed by the GC, even if it does its job (depending in which heap segment live your object, it could be ignored by the GC. there is a special phase called a "full GC" that will traverse the complete heap, looking for unreferenced object - but nobody knows when it will be called). any implementation relying on that is broken. WeakReference is the best you can have

Comment: maybe you could flag your object as "pendingDeletion", and use that flag in your loop to ignore them?

Comment: so, my concern for this was lets say a thread was created 1000's time and it registered with class A with weakreference. Now when gc finds it that the memory is low it would remove the objects right ?

Comment: yes it could, only if you don't have another strong reference on it. but there is no guarantee when it will happen. more formally, the weakreference will still be here, but the method ```get``` will return ```null```. Look at SoftReference, which are specifically designed to adjust depending on memory usage